# $(X/H)/(G/H)=X/G$? Here $G$ is a topological group acting continuously on $X$, $H$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a [topological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) [acting continuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_group_action) on a topological space $X$ (on the left, denoted by $g\cdot x$, $g\in G, x\in X$), $H$ be a closed normal subgroup of $G$. Then

> 1. The quotient group $G/H = \{gH\mid g\in G\}$ becomes a topological group when given the [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)).
> 2. The continuous group action of $G$ on $X$ induces a quotient topology on the [orbit space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) $X/G:=\{G\cdot x \mid x\in X\}$. The quotient space $X/H$ is defined in the same way.
> 3. The continuous group action of $G$ on $X$ induces a (left) continuous group action of $G/H$ on $X/H$ by:
>      $$gH\cdot (H\cdot x) := H\cdot(g\cdot x),\quad x\in X, g\in G.$$
>      This action also induces a quotient topological space $(X/H)/(G/H)$.

---

The natural question is, what relations are there between $(X/H)/(G/H)$ and $X/G$? It's easy to verify that they are the same **set**, and the quotient topology on $(X/H)/(G/H)$ is coarser than that on $X/G$ (by the [universal property of quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties)).

So what I'm wondering is whether the two quotient topologies are the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the two quotient topologies are the same. Just using the more detailed universal property of quotient topology presented in [Munkres' topology book, Theorem 22.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=XjoZAQAAIAAJ&q=Munkres+topology+Theorem+22.2&dq=Munkres+topology+Theorem+22.2&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj769Te6IzeAhWMvVMKHTK6DOEQ6AEIODAC).

**PS:** This conclusion may be referred to as the third [isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).