# Is the group action of quotient group $G/H$ on quotient manifold $M/H$ proper?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

My question arises from Chapter 21 of Lee's book, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition*.

---

Let $G$ be a Lie group [acting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) smoothly, freely and properly on a manifold $M$ on the left, denoted by $g\cdot p$, $g\in G, p\in M$. Let $H$ be a closed normal subgroup of $G$. Then we have the following conclusions by some theorems in Lee's book

> - By [Quotient Manifold Theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA544&lpg=PA544&dq=Theorem+21.10+(Quotient+Manifold+Theorem).&source=bl&ots=j0JsSX_cWW&sig=GqosxX_7X6VsBK7et-PFxURRoIU&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-kI7nveXdAhXHnuAKHUEaAx8Q6AEwBHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Theorem%2021.10%20(Quotient%20Manifold%20Theorem).&f=false), the orbit space $M/G$ is a smooth manifold, such that the quotient map $\pi_G:M \to M/G$ is a smooth submersion;
> - For the same reason, $M/H$ is a smooth manifold such that the quotient map $\pi_H:M \to M/H$ is a smooth submersion;
> - By [Homogeneous Space Construction Theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=w4bhBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&dq=Lee+Homogeneous+Space+Construction+Theorem&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQqLzav47eAhVPy1MKHeTgBUUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Lee%20Homogeneous%20Space%20Construction%20Theorem&f=false), the coset space $G/H$ is a homogeneous $G$-space;
> - By [Quotient Theorem for Lie Groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA555&lpg=PA555&dq=%22Quotient+Theorem+for+Lie+Groups%22&source=bl&ots=j0JsSYVhVP&sig=Zh3GukwYKPXcGVfkEuY5bbF7rbg&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia49id0uXdAhVCh-AKHSH9BQQQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Quotient%20Theorem%20for%20Lie%20Groups%22&f=false), $G/H$ is also a Lie group.

By another [question on topological group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958954/x-h-g-h-x-g-here-g-is-a-topological-group-acting-continuously-on-x), we also know that

> - The group action of $G$ on $M$ induces a (left) group action of $G/H$ on $M/H$ by:
>     \begin{equation}\tag{1}
>   gH\cdot (H\cdot p) := H\cdot(g\cdot p),\quad p\in M, g\in G.
>   \end{equation}
> - The induced action of $G/H$ on $M/H$ is also smooth and free.
> - The quotient spaces $(M/H)/(G/H)$ and $M/G$ are identical as sets, and have same quotient topology.

---

The natural question is, **whether the induced action defined in $(1)$ is proper?** If so, then the quotient manifold $(M/H)/(G/H)$ is well defined, and we can easily check that $(M/H)/(G/H)$ and $M/G$ have same smooth structure (by [Quotient Manifold Theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA544&lpg=PA544&dq=Theorem+21.10+(Quotient+Manifold+Theorem).&source=bl&ots=j0JsSX_cWW&sig=GqosxX_7X6VsBK7et-PFxURRoIU&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-kI7nveXdAhXHnuAKHUEaAx8Q6AEwBHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Theorem%2021.10%20(Quotient%20Manifold%20Theorem).&f=false)). But I do not know how to check this properness...

I can say more in the very special case that $H$ and $G/H$ are both compact subgroups. By [Exercise 13 in Section 26 of Munkres' topology book](https://books.google.com/books?id=XjoZAQAAIAAJ&q=Munkres+Let+H+be+a+compact+subgroup+of+G&dq=Munkres+Let+H+be+a+compact+subgroup+of+G&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2252Rv47eAhWJz1MKHf1jBDkQ6AEIKDAA), $G$ is also compact. Then by [Corollary 21.6 in Lee's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA544&dq=Lee+Corollary+21.6&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhwOq6v47eAhXK3lMKHZqBD08Q6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=Lee%20Corollary%2021.6&f=false), the two group actions of $G$ on $M$ and $G/H$ on $M/H$ are both proper.